# How to detect if user has left the input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Suppose I have an input field,

```
<input id="city" placeholder="city">
```

and I want to detect whenever user leaves this field. How can I do so?

Comment: JS event: `onblur` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Comment: `$('#city').on('blur', function() { ... })`, this should be trivial to figure out by searching Google or reading the documentation

Comment: I can't just think of any use of `blur` that won't go on user's nerves.

Comment: thanks adeneo. i need to put this in one of the input fields to check if there is a data.

Answer (score 8):

#### Normal javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById("ELEMENT_ID");
element.addEventListener("blur", function() { ... your code here ...});
```

#### jQuery

```
$("#ELEMENT_ID").on("blur",  function() { ... your code here ...});
```

---

If, by any chance, you're implementing those self-emptying fields with predefined text, use [`placeholder` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder). If you're changing style based on focus, use [`:focus` CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Afocus). Also, `change` event is emitted if user leaves the field **and** changed it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

When an element loses focus, the `onblur` event is fired.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('city');
elem.addEventListener("blur", function( event ) {
    console.log('Elvis has left the city (input)!');
}, true);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Comment: Here is an example on JSFiddle... if you have any problems, you may be using an older version of Internet Explorer, which uses `attachEvent` rather than `addEventListener`. http://jsfiddle.net/rbao8Lm6/